# Why does Stack Overflow restrict almost any users activity without points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I've been using Stack Overflow for a long time and constantly try to vote for my favorite answers to other people's questions, but for some reason Stack Overflow still limits my actions on the platform by requiring points, without which I can do almost nothing, excluding searching for questions.

I consider that Stack Overflow has collected enough data to make a behavioral model for judging "am I a worthy user or not?"

Why does Stack Overflow still not have a user behavioral score, since I think it's clear from my activity on this site that I'm not a bot and let me vote for other people's answers to questions?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123918/what-is-the-benefit-of-reputation-on-stack-overflow

Comment: You can do a lot of stuff without much points: ask questions, or answer them. Do you miss anything that you want to do additionally?

Comment: "*I consider that stackoverflow has collected enough data to make a behavioral model for judging "am I a worthy user or not?"*" what data? [Your profile barely shows any activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12234022/klaymen-tv?tab=activity&sort=all). It doesn't show votes but that's hardly data about worthyness.

Comment: You've yet to prove you can write a good question or answer. For a Q&A site this is a must

Comment: The only activity I see on your account is posting on the wrong site of the network. Perhaps you want to [edit] the meta question to clarify how you expect the site to guess whether you are "a worthy user or not".

Comment: "I consider that Stack Overflow has collected enough data to make a behavioral model for judging "am I a worthy user or not?"" - ... how? You'd need a person to do that. But there are millions of active users. Please don't tell me we're going into AI territory again.

Comment: No idea why you're so downvoted, this is a legit question that makes sense. I have the opinion that after using the service regularly for years even without posting answers or questions, one would be eligible to determine if an answer is upvote/downvote worthy and also post legit comments. But apparently we're the only ones to think that. Even asking seems to be forbidden and unwanted according to the downvotes.

Comment: @SamuelGfeller on meta things generally get downvoted when people are essentially getting tired of it being brought up yet again. Meta dwellers are a pretty steady bunch of exactly the same folks. It doesn't imply the question is bad, just... tiring.

Comment: This is not "points", this is rep.

Comment: @SamuelGfeller While I think the general topic is worth discussing, it's still unclear to me what *this* question wants to discuss in specific. [The "why" seems adequately covered in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and elsewhere on meta. So what's the "usage" under discussion here – lurking, browsing, looking at answers, questions, …? Seeing the question itself demonstrate such usage is insufficient to get a proper understanding of what goes where on SO, what *argument* is there to support taking it into account for privileges?

Comment: Fair points. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fact that you've been using the site for a long time doesn't make you a trustworthy user any more than spending a lot of time in a doctor's office makes you a doctor.

I would encourage you to make positive contributions to the site by doing stuff like answering questions and making useful edits. That's how you become a trusted user here.

Answer (score 20):

Stack Overflow follows a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) based model. These privileges are earned by gaining [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). There are various reasons such a model is needed on Stack Overflow, and following are some of the reasons:

- **Prevent spam**: If there isn't any privilege system, spammers can very easily create accounts and flood us with spam posts.
- **Prevent abuse by users**: There are users who abuse the system in various ways by serial voting, creating sock puppets, and various other ways. Having a reputation barrier makes it harder for such users to abuse the system.
- **User On-boarding**: Stack Overflow's model is not as simple as it might look to a naive user. Earning privileges based on reputation allows the users to have time to slowly get used to the various features available to them and allows them to better understand the model, preventing them from making mistakes or causing damage that they might have if they were given all of the privileges from the start.
- **Community curation**: Stack Overflow is majorly curated by the community, i.e., normal users like us. Given this, users need access to certain features that could be easily abused if given to all users. Having privileges based on reputation allows establishing some form of trust level the system should have for a particular user, hence allowing users to do curation.

Answer (score 3):

There are rules for everything.

When you’re trying to upvote your favourite answers, I guess you're seeing a message that says that you need 15 reputation to upvote.

So, you need to earn points like other Stack Overflow users. It's not about data collection; what you contribute to the community will earn you points. Check the [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/) during your leisure time and provide helpful answers.

Comment: After posting some answers and questions, it's true that I can now better determine the quality of a post, and I'm able to make “legit” comments what I couldn't do before /s. No it didn't, it's something completely different. I'm with @KlayMenTV on this one, contributing does and did absolutely not change how I judge questions. It bothered me not being able to do anything when I didn't have enough karma and StackOverflow could've easily known that I'm not a bot or fake account. I still think it doesn't make sense today. Not comparing, but reddit works well and doesn't have such restrictions.

Comment: @SamuelGfeller How could SO have "easily known you're not a bot or fake account"? CAPTCHA's are rather well known to be easier to complete with AI rather than humans, and right now we're having a pretty big problem with a certain AI making a lot of posts that look good, but have subtle details making their answers worthless or outright harmful. That's before we even get into the problems with how difficult it is to regulate socks, for which IP tracking and fingerprinting are trivial to bypass.

Comment: I'm surprised by this question, there are so many ways… The first things that come to mind that could influence the algo that rates the legibility of users are: frequency a user comes on the site, time the account spends on questions, text it selects and copies, scrolling and other “human” behaviour on the site. If a user comes on the site in average lets say 10 to 500 times a week, stays an average of more than 20sec on the questions, upvotes occasionally etc. SO is very smart and I'm sure it already does this kind of analytics and I have no doubt that it exactly knows which users are real.

Comment: It's not about knowing whether or not you are fake; rather, once you've invested time in SO and earned reputation, you now have a vested interest in keeping your account and are given more privileges. Abuse the privileges, and you lose the ability to do anything. The more reputation you have, the more privileges you get and the more you have to lose by abusing them. It's a standard trust model.

Comment: I was replying to @vandench. Yes, it's an opinion thing. I just remember when my account had less than 50 karma, how annoying it was to not be able to post real pertinent comments or upvote good answers. Had to post an answer once because I couldn't write a comment. I had to artificially try to increase my karma to properly being able to interact and use the forum. I get the reputation thing with privileges, but I absolutely don't agree with what those privileges allow and not. How does it make sense that you cannot write comments but post entire answers when you don't have a lot of karma?

Comment: @SamuelGfeller Answers and comments are curated quite differently. Posting an answer bumps the Q&A, there are manually triggered and automated reviews, …; in other words, answers naturally draw attention to be curated by users. Comments not so much, they are for more trusted users that don't need every action double checked.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi would you be satisfied by this answer you've given? This is not an excuse at all, I mean it's not so hard to implement a system where for instance comments from users with less than 50 karma are prompted to curated users and automated reviews. Almost have the feeling that the majority here are just conservative sheeps that follow and try to find excuses for the rules and functions in place without second thinking them, downvoting everyone that dares expressing their opinion and upvoting people that match theirs regardless of the quality. This won't improve the forum for sure.

Comment: @SamuelGfeller "…it's not so hard to implement…" Implementing isn't the problem. Getting people to actually *contribute* to it is. Seeing how my effort to curate and review questions and answers on SO all too often leads to subtle and not at all subtle jabs (was the "conservative sheeps" and all that followed it really necessary?) – heck no, I'm not going to waste any more of my time for that audience.